# java unreported exception java.lang.Exception error when compiling for code incorporating weka

Tags: java, weka

I'm writing a wrapper that needs to import some functions from the weka library; however, it's throwing me the following error:

unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown

My code is below:

```
import java.io.*;
import weka.core.Instances;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class wrapper
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    try
    {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec("python frequency_counter_two.py nono 400 0");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new         
        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        p.waitFor();
        String line = "";
        while (br.ready())
            System.out.println(br.readLine());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    String cause = e.getMessage();
    if (cause.equals("python: not found"))
        System.out.println("No python interpreter found.");
    }

run_weka();


}



public static int run_weka()
{

DataSource source = new DataSource("features_ten_topics_10_unigrams_0_bigrams.csv");
Instances data = source.getDataSet();
// setting class attribute if the data format does not provide this information
// For example, the XRFF format saves the class attribute information as well
if (data.classIndex() == -1)
     data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

/*

double percent = 66.0; 
Instances inst = data; // your full training set 
instances.randomize(java.util.Random);
int trainSize = (int) Math.round(inst.numInstances() * percent / 100); 
int testSize = inst.numInstances() - trainSize; 
Instances train = new Instances(inst, 0, trainSize); 
Instances test = new Instances(inst, trainSize, testSize);

// train classifier
Classifier cls = new J48();
cls.buildClassifier(train);
// evaluate classifier and print some statistics
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
eval.evaluateModel(cls, test);
System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false)); 

*/
}

}
```

any idea of what might be going on?

Comment: Don't you use an IDE? Although I do not know weka, I'm pretty sure that your "run_weka" method must rethrow or catch some exceptions...

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the Exceptions thrown from the DataSource constructor and getDataSet() in run_weka().

If you check the docs you can see that they both throw java.lang.Exception: http://crdd.osdd.net/man/wiki/weka/core/converters/ConverterUtils.DataSource.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is saying that some of the weka methods could throw an Exception, so you need to write some code to handle this occurance.

In this case, you would probably change your method to do something like this...

```
public static int run_weka() {
    Instances data;

    try {
        DataSource source = new DataSource("features_ten_topics_10_unigrams_0_bigrams.csv");
        data = source.getDataSet();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        return -1;
    }

    // setting class attribute if the data format does not provide this information
    // For example, the XRFF format saves the class attribute information as well
    if (data.classIndex() == -1)
         data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
    /*
    Your commented code...
    */
    }
}
```